# Generated xorg.conf by Nvidia drivers for 2 monitors is not correct - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: xorg.conf

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on an Asus Laptop with a Nvidia RTX 2060 videocard.
My drivers versions is 470.82 .
I have attached an additional monitor, which works via USB-C - display port adapter.
Both monitors are working and are detected by Nvidia drivers - the laptop integrated monitor and additional monitor.
If I try to save the xorg.conf from Nvidia drivers, Nvidia generates an xorg.conf that contains only the external monitor.

After that, when I restart the laptop, only the external monitor is working.
So I need to leave a blank xorg.conf file, to have both monitors working.

Is there any solution so a correct xorg.conf file will be generated, with both monitors?